# Performant matrix-matrix multiplication in Javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to port some basic MATLAB to Javascript and have been a little disappointed by the performance in JS, be it Chrome or Firefox. I've optimized slightly by tranposing one of the matrices, unrolled the inner loop and used Float64Arrays:

```
function vvdot_body(rollsize)
{
 var body = '';

 body += ' var acc, ni, nj, nr, rs, lo, i;\n';
 body += ' acc = 0.0;\n';
 body += ' rs = ' + rollsize + ';\n';
 body += ' nr = Math.floor(n / rs);\n';
 body += ' lo = n - (nr * rs);\n';
 body += ' for (i=0; i<nr; i++) {\n';
 body += '  ni = aos + i * rs;\n';
 body += '  nj = bos + i * rs;\n';

 /* begin unroll */
 body += '  acc += a[ni] * b[nj] ';
 for (var i=1; i<rollsize; i++)
  body += ' + a[ni + ' + i + '] * b[nj + ' + i + ']';
 body += ';\n }\n'
 /* done unroll */

 /* handle leftover */
 body += ' ni = aos + nr * rs;\n';
 body += ' nj = bos + nr * rs;\n';
 body += ' for (i=0; i<lo; i++)\n';
 body += '  acc += a[ni + i] * b[nj + i];\n\n';

 body += ' return acc;';

 return body;
}

function mkvvdot(rollsize)
{
 var args = 'a,b,n,aos,bos'
   , body = vvdot_body(rollsize);
 return new Function(args, body);
}

/* transpose */
function T(b, n, bT) {
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      bT[i * n + j] = b[j * n + i];
    }
  }
}

function mkmmm(unroll) {
  var vvdot = mkvvdot(unroll);
  return function(a, b, c, n) {
   var bT = new Float64Array(n*n);
   T(b, n, bT);
   for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
     c[i * n + j] = vvdot(a, bT, n, i * n, j * n);
    }
   }
 }
}
```

The following JS Fiddle runs a benchmark

http://jsfiddle.net/42nmw4yx/2/

On my machine (E5-1650), variation over unrolling in the vector dot inner loop shows peaks performance of ~2.6 Gflops in Chrome 40, ~1.0 in Firefox 35, while MATLAB, single core, runs 15-20 Gflops.

It may seem unfair to compare a naive algorithm in JS to a vendor's linear algebra library (MKL), and I could accept 50% performance loss but an order of magnitude seems unreasonable in 2015.

What can I do here besides (ab)using WebGL to do the computation? Potential answers fall in categories of 1) Javascript, i.e don't use anonymous functions (which are in fact not slower) 2) linear algebra tricks, i.e. tranpose one of the matrices (which I've already done, with a nice speedup) 3) other?

*EDIT* Corrected flops/s to simply flops. Also, I ran the bencmark on reference NumPy installation (Debian packages), which showed the same performance within error as Javascript, so the great different in performance appears due to the almighty-ness of the MKL. Long live the MKL & vendor tuned libraries..

Comment: Have you tried using Web Workers already? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage

Comment: Have you looked at existing performant javascript linear algebra libraries already? Also, multiplications are slow in JS, try to avoid them. Follow general JS performance tricks, e.g. write i|0 instead of Math.floor(i). Look into asm.js for better performance in FF.

Comment: Thanks for the tips: putting the code into a worker improved ~8%. asm.js gave FF a 10% boost, but slowed Chrome down. The i|0 trick didn't help much but wasn't in the inner loop. Final jsfiddle with animated benchmark: http://jsfiddle.net/42nmw4yx/3/

Comment: I didn't wade through your code in detail, but there is potential for improvement: E.g. replace nr = (n / rs) | 0; with nr = (n * ' + 1/rollsize + ') | 0; to get rid of a very slow division, use similar techniques to get rid of multiplications in the inner loop, e.g. instead of computing i * rs twice per loop have a counter increment by ' + rollsize + ';... you probably could push the nr = ... ; lo = ...; computation to be precomputed as well etc. Still impressed by your 'templating' technique; does it improve performance much?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use SIMD.JS. It is currently supported in Firefox, but not yet in the Chrome. On the ohter hand there is Crosswalk (https://crosswalk-project.org/) which is built using Chromium source base and which is available on many platforms.

SIMD instructions are accessible in Intel® Core™ and Intel® Atom™ processors, as well as ARM* processors.

Comment: Firefox nightly only (and only if you are [lucky](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/3198))

Comment: In Chrome use a flag  --js-flags="--harmony-simd". Not sure if that's running on a polyfill or real SIMD

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Firefox(Nightly)
https://jsperf.com/simdmat4

You can also try this in Chrome with a flag --js-flags="--harmony-simd"

In firefox SIMD is 3 times faster, in Chrome is 20 times slower(Chrome still using a polyfill?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- divide matrix into 16x16 sized submatrices
- do the multiplication only using submatrices
- use memoization on each submatrix so that accessing 16x16 causes the program to access only 256-element buffers instead of full buffer with 1024 2048 etc stride.

Getting rid of strided access should make Javascript function faster.